# Генерация сообщения с выбранными товарами в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

У меня есть список в котором хранятся кортежи с информацией о товаре.

```
cart = [
    (6754, 'Футболка', '50 грн', 'XL'),
    (666, 'Кроссовки Abibas', '300 грн', '39'),
    (7954, 'Штаны', '40 гривень', 'XXXXXXL')
]
```

Количество товаров может быть разное, и я не буду его знать, поэтому нужно сгенерировать сообщение выбранные товары пользователем.

Мне нужно отправить сообщение в Телеграмм боте по команде "/cart", где и будут те самые товары. Но я не могу понять как это можно реализовать.
Сообщение должно выглядеть примерно так:
[image: Пример сообщения]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В красивом оформлении:

```
beautiful_message = (
        ' Список товаров в корзине:'
        '\n\n'
        f'       1. {cart[0][1]}:\n'
        f'          Цена: {cart[0][2]}\n'
        f'          Размер: {cart[0][3]}\n'
        '\n'
        f'       2. {cart[1][1]}:\n'
        f'          Цена: {cart[1][2]}\n'
        f'          Размер: {cart[1][3]}\n'
        '\n'
        f'       3. {cart[2][1]}:\n'
        f'          Цена: {cart[2][2]}\n'
        f'          Размер: {cart[2][3]}\n'
    )
```

Также вы можете использовать цикл, который будет генерировать это сообщение, чтобы не пришлось писать постоянно вручную.. а сделать это можно пройдясь двумя циклами, сперва по всем имеющимся товарам, после по данным в каждом из кортежей для получения информации о товаре, в итоге получаем такую карусель:

```
beautiful_message = (' Список товаров в корзине:\n\n')

for product in cart:
    for beauty_text in range(len(product)):
        if beauty_text != 0 and beauty_text == 1:
            beautiful_message += f'     {cart.index(product)+1}. {product[beauty_text]}:\n'
        elif beauty_text == 2:
            beautiful_message += f'         Цена: {product[beauty_text]}\n'
        elif beauty_text == 3:
            beautiful_message += f'         Размер: {product[beauty_text]}\n\n'

# весь текст расположен в переменной beautiful_message
```

Comment: Это понятно, но я не знаю сколько товаров в списке заранее. Например у какого-то пользователя 7 товаров в корзине, а в другого 4, соответственно первому нужно отправить 7 товаров, а другому 4. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Я вас понял, думал что просто нужно красиво отправить сообщение)

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate(cart: tuple) -> str:
    result = " Список товаров в корзине:"
    if len(cart) == 0:
        result += f"\n\n{' '*8}Корзина пуста."

    for index, item in enumerate(cart):
        result += f"\n\n{' '*8}{index+1}. {item[1]}:\n{' '*12}Цена: {item[2]}\n{' '*12}Размер: {item[3]}"
    return result
```

Результат работы функции, полностью готовое сообщение:

[image]

Можете сами отредактировать параметры `{' '*8}`, чтобы задать другой отступ (*8 это кол-во пробелов).

Answer (score -1):

Используйте [aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/).

Либо [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).

Нужная для вас информация и примеры есть в документации.

Для форматирования `\n` и прочее используйте.

Comment: Пользователь ясно написал, что знает как отправить сообщение, зачем вы на вопрос отвечаете левым текстом? Ему нужно отправить сообщение "красиво"

Comment: Я знаю как отправлять сообщения, я не знаю как отправить список чтоб он выглядел не уродливо. Если просто отправляю переменную cart, отправляется что-то типа этого - [(1, 794782785, 'Футболка', 124, 'Чёрный', 'XL'), (2, 794782785, 'Кроссовки Nike', 600, 'Чёрно-синий', '43'), (4, 794782785, 'Штаны', 40, 'Синий', 'XL')]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: подправил ответ выше

Comment: ну, а если уж не знаешь как обратиться к кортежу внутри списка, зачем лезть в создание ботов, основы бы подтянуть

Comment: cart[0][0]. Но! Я не знаю сколько в списке товаров заранее. Например у какого-то пользователя 7 товаров в корзине, а в другого 4, соответственно первому нужно отправить 7 товаров, а другому 4.