# Генерация сообщений с выбранными товарами в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть **список** в котором хранятся **кортежи** с информацией о товаре

```
>>> db.get_cart(id)
[(784324, 5733, 'Рубашка', 100, 'Белый', 'XL', 3), (784324, 7842, 'Свитер', 150, 'Коричневый', 'XL', 1), (784324, 8421, 'Штаны', 40, 'Синий', 'XL', 3)]

#(1. id пользователя; 2. id товара; 3. Название товара; 4. Цена; 5. Цвет; 6. Размер; 7. Количество.)
```

Я не могу реализовать вывод этих товаров в сообщении так чтоб оно выглядело ***"красиво"***, так как изначально **у меня нет количества товаров в списке**.

***Например:*** **У первого юзера 5 товаров** в корзине, а **у другого всего 2**. Мне нужно вывести **первому 5 товаров**, а **второму соответственно 2**.[image: Пример]

*Надеюсь у меня получилось объяснить.*

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на этот вопрос, где я уже дал ответ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1338170/427052
В вашем случае это будет выглядеть примерно так, мог ошибиться с индексами, но если что вы и сами их легко поправите.

```
def generate(cart: tuple) -> str:
    result = " Список товаров в корзине:"
    if len(cart) == 0:
        result += f"\n\n{' '*8}Корзина пуста."

    for index, item in enumerate(cart):
        result += f"\n\n{' '*8}{index+1}. {item[2]}:\n{' '*12}Цена: {item[3]}\n{' '*12}Размер: {item[5]}"
    return result
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!